# Example of a discrete measure for Tableau pills?

Tags: tableau-api, measure, binning

Can someone define what a *discrete measure* is by providing concrete examples? I am trying to understand what the Tableau pill discrete measure type is.

**Update**

I know what *discrete* and *continuous* means. I also know what a *measure* is. However, I am unclear what a *discrete measure* could be since measures tend to be computed on continuous values. Is it a measure where the sum (for example) is binned?

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the official Tableau documentation:

> Continuous means "forming an unbroken whole, without interruption"; discrete means "individually separate and distinct." In Tableau, fields can be either continuous or discrete. When you drag a field from the Measures area to Columns or Rows, the values are continuous by default and Tableau creates an axis.

See more here:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#datafields_typesandroles.html%3FTocPath%3DGet%2520Started%7CTableau%2520Concepts%7C_____1

In practice, a date range can be continuous and an example of a discreet value could be day of the week (e.g. Wednesday), where the available values are 'individually separate and distinct'.

If your unsure, you can always switch between the two in Tableau and see how this effects the appearance of your chart/data.

Some examples from the docs linked above:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two independent decisions when you use a field in a Tableau visualization.

1. Do you want to treat the field as a dimension or measure (and if a measure, how do you want to aggregate values, SUM(), AVG() ...)?
2. Do you want to treat the field as discrete or continuous when rendering the visualization?

The first decision defines the database query (and thus the query results), sets the level of detail of the viz (and thus the number of marks) -- i.e. impacts the actual values.

The second decision impacts how those values are presented visually -- i.e. whether you create separate rows or column headers or use a continuous axis, individual colors or a spectrum.

For the most part, they are completely independent decisions, and you can treat a field differently in different circumstances to get different results. So dimensions are usually discrete but don't have to be. Measures are usually continuous but don't have to be.

As Ben P mentioned, date fields can be treated many different ways, and are a good example of a field that can be used as a continuous dimension. Any time series is a good example of that.